# Visual Studio 2017 in Azure VM - not way to change IE Security Zone

Tags: visual-studio, azure, internet-explorer, azure-virtual-machine

Good offering in Azure to use Visual Studio 2017 on a VM (Datacenter 2016). But when you open VS and click 'Sign in' it opens up a window which is BLANK. So you can't sign in AT ALL. This is because IE Security Level Zone in the settings is set to High. Now, I change it to Medium -> click OK... Nothing changed! It stays at High!

This is driving me nuts! How to change this "№%№;% security zone?

So this offering is completely unusable!

Comment: Is your resource `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on Windows Server 2016(x64)`?

Comment: yes, that one …

Comment: In server manager try turning off advanced security

Comment: done at first login, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my lab. You can follow these steps below:

1. launch the **Internet Options**, select Internet zone, select **custom level**,locate to **Scripting**- **Active scripting**, select **enable** and click OK and **apply**. 
   [image]
2. Then choose the **Privacy** tab under Internet Options, select **Advanced** under Settings. Verify if there are two **Accept** options, then click **OK**. **Note** clicking OK is an important thing that we must do.
   [image]
3. After the above steps, go back to sign in again, it look normal.